# No module named 'discord.enums'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I am making a discord.py bot obviously, and I keep getting this error. I don't really know what enums is.

[Here is my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GP1GR.png)

Here is my main.py code

```
import discord
import os
import requests
import asyncio
import random
import datetime
import aiofiles
import settings
import utils
#from keep_alive import keep_alive
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands

intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(intents=intents, case_insensitive=True, command_prefix="$")
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)



class reportModal(discord.ui.Modal):
    def __init__(self):
    super().__init__("Report a user breaking the rules") 
    
    report_title = discord.ui.TextInput(
        style=discord.TextInputStyle.short,
        label="User",
        required=True,
        placeholder="Name of the user you are reporting"
    )
    message = discord.ui.TextInput(
        style=discord.TextInputStyle.paragraph,
        label="User",
        required=True,
        max_length=500,
        placeholder="Why are you reporting them"
    )

async def load_cogs():
    for filename in os.listdir('./commands'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            await client.load_extension(f'commands.{filename[:-3]}')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    os.system("clear")
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game('on SolarMC'))

    await tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id=1143316054030954526))

    print(f'Connected to: {client.user}')
    print(f'Bot ID: {client.user.id}')
  
    await load_cogs()

@tree.command(title="report", description="Report a user for breaking the rules")
async def report_cmd(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    report_modal = reportModal()
    await interaction.response.send_modal(feedback_modal)


client.run(...)
```

I have tried pretty much anything I could think of.  I messed around with importing libraries, etc.  I didn't expect anything to happen because I really have no idea what enums is, so I'm not sure how I can fix it.

Comment: Welcome, please don't post error messages as images. I cannot fathom the effort it takes to upload an image of text that you can't simply paste as text .

Comment: I think discord.py version is not compatible. Try using upgrade or degrate the version of discord.py

Comment: @Phix I tried to but it wouldn't let me copy the console, my apologies

Comment: @MahboobNur It was working earlier until I added trees.  Are trees causing it?  Also, I have tried like 10 or so different versions.

Comment: For testing purpose, you can remove trees and try . Check wether it is working or not.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reinstalling discord.py. 
You should be able to do it be using `python -m pip install --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir discord.py`